# ¿Cómo subir una una imagen predeterminada si no se elije una por el usuario?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo un formulario donde el usuario puede subir su foto de perfil, pero si no la escoge, entonces quiero subir una imagen predeterminada almacenada en una carpeta.

Tengo una función donde el usuario sube su imagen, pero si no elije nada no se como implementar esta función para que me elija la imagen predeterminada. ¿Alguna idea de como resolver esto?

Este es mi codigo:

```
public function addUser($infoUser, $file)
    {   
        $conexion = new Connection();
        $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
        
        $photo = $file['name'];
        $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $directorio_destino = "images";
        $img_size = $file['size'];
        $img_type = $file['type'];

        $upload_dir = '../imgs/profile/'; // upload directory 

        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($photo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); //get image extension

        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', ''); // valid extension 

        // $userpic = rand(1000, 1000000).".".$imgExt; //rename uploading image

        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){

            if ($img_size < 1000000) {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir.$userpic);
            }else{
            $error_message = "<script>alert('Su archivo de imagen es muy grande, solo se permite 1MB'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
            echo $error_message;
            }
        }else{
            $error_message = "<script>alert('Solo archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF son permitidos'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
            echo $error_message;
        }
}
```

Comment: Y por qué subir una imagen predeterminada si ya la tienes en el servidor?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que al hacer el registro, hay 3 imágenes que se muestran, el usuario podrá escoger una de ellas. Entonces en la BD quiero que se inserte esta imagen que escogió el usuario.

Comment: y no te resultaría más sencillo almacenar la elección del usuario en lugar de la ruta a la imagen seleccionada?

Comment: No comprendo al 100 % la idea que me comentas

Comment: Solo deberías hacer la validación del campo recibido como ya anteriormente te lo indican, pero si quieres hacerlo mas dinámico podrías implementar esta librería [laravolt/avatar](https://github.com/laravolt/avatar), esta librería te ayuda con la creación de avatares por Iniciales del Nombre y Apellido [![avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xwrQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xwrQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

si quieres guardar una imagen predeterminada, solo debes validar antes de hacer tu INSERT bien seria algo asi;

```
<?php
if (!empty($photo)){
$tmp_name ="img/imagendefaul.png";
}else{
$tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
}
?>
```